# Determining the version of Razor Mediator installed

Tags: 2011, configuration, razormediator

I am setting up a new SDL Tridion environment and need to install the Razor Mediator (on both the Content Manager and Publisher servers).

I want to make sure that the environment that I am setting up is the same as the rest of the DTAP environments.  Is there a way to determine which version of the Razor Mediator has been installed on these?

I know that it is either version 1.2 or 1.3 installed because of the inclusion of the import attribute in the configuration.

Here is the Razor section of the Tridion.ContentManager.config file from the Development server:

```
<razor.mediator cacheTime="60" extractBinaries="true" adminUser="DOMAIN\AdminUser">
    <namespaces></namespaces>
    <assemblies></assemblies>
    <imports>
        <!-- I've added the ... below for brevity -->
        <add import="/webdav/200 Global Design/.../System/Razor_Template_Functions.cshtml"/>
    </imports>
</razor.mediator>
```

(In the 'Programs and Features' section of the Control Panel the version number is quoted as v1.0.0, but I know that this isn't correct.)

Thanks,
Jonathan

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the razor mediator installer.

Comment: Thanks Dominic.  Alex's answer below resolved this for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check the version installed by looking at the configSections element in the Tridion.ContentManager.config file, at the section for the razor.mediator.

```
<section name="razor.mediator" type="Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Configuration.RazorMediatorConfigurationSection, Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5eeceedb34d9dfd7" />
```

Alternatively, you could also look at the file directly in the GAC, which should be at:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor\v4.0_1.2.0.0__5eeceedb34d9dfd7\Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.dll

Comment: Perfect - Thanks Alex.  Both of these mechanisms confirmed that version 1.2 is installed.